# Android studio Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to create a React Native app on Android emulator.

However, I keep getting the error message below when trying to start up the emulator. It crashes with the following:

```
16:07   ADB rejected shell command (getprop): closed

16:07   Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Is there a way to fix this issue? Sorry I am new to android studio

Answer (score 0):

Try to restartthe adb server.
Go to C/users/(username)/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
 In the command prompt by doing

```
cd C/users/(username)/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

and then run

```
adb kill-server

adb start-server
```

Note that the above command may change depending upon the installed location of your sdk in system.