# Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to create a React Native app on Android emulator.

However, I keep getting the error message below when trying to start up the emulator. It crashes with the following:

```
Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I am not able to write this as a comment but here is a reference to a possible fix:

> [Link to possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51970270/android-studio-emulator-process-finished-with-exit-code-1073740791-0xc0000409)

It is easier to find more details to an error code by searching for (0xC0000409). You can also search with "exact match" to find more details. I don't have experience with "React Native" but I hope it may point you in the right direction.